# Edit permalink for certain pages

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls, links

I'm creating a website based on an old and positioned one.

I've created all the sections and I need to know how can I add "/services/" as a prefix for some pages... I mean, not all pages are services, so for those that are, I want to add the "services" folder before the page name. It would be something like this in the end: `mysite.com/services/marketing-strategy.` instead of `mysite.com/marketing-strategy.` as it is now.

I tried editing the permaking but it removes the slash ( / ) character. Also permalinks configuration applies to ALL pages, and I need this to be only on some of them. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: The simplest solution is going to be to create a `services` page and assign it as parent when editing your other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Milo it would be easiest to do it by having the Services Page as your top level page (parent) and then declare other pages as the Services pages' children.

You can do this on the page editing area in the WP admin area.

Try not to mess with the permalinks as that can have crazy consequences on things working as they should. If that solution doesn't work out, create a custom post type of services. That way anything in that custom post type will be under the services type!

There are a variety of plugins to help with this. You could also write your own plugin to do this too!